# Посоветуйте актуальную библиотеку для OCR

Tags: c#, .net

Все кроме tessnet2 и Aspose.OCR. Хотелось бы узнать что еще есть из этого сегмента.
Платная или бесплатная - не важно, главное хорошая ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Asprice OCR SDK](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/download.php?lang=csharp)
2. [ImageGear for .NET](http://www.accusoft.com/ig-net.htm)
3. [Office 2007 OCR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29172/Converting-Images-to-Text-using-Office-2007-OCR-Op)

Третий пункт для любителей странного :)

Answer (score 2):

ABBYY является мировым лидером в области оптического распознавания символов. Компания предоставляет сразу несколько решений для разработчиков:

1. [ABBYY FineReader Engine](http://www.abbyy.ru/finereader-engine/?utm_source=ru.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) — известная во всем мире технология оптического распознавания символов (OCR SDK). Именно эта технология распознавания лежит в основе FineReader.
2. [ABBYY FlexiCapture Engine](http://www.abbyy.ru/flexicapture-engine/?utm_source=ru.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) — технология, направленная на потоковый ввод данных.
3. [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.ru/mobile-ocr-engine/?utm_source=ru.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) — технология, предназначенная для работы на мобильных устройствах (менее требовательная к ресурсам, чем FineReader Engine).
4. [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com?utm_source=ru.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) (сайт на английском) — тот же FineReader Engine, но работает в облаке через Web-API. Так же это наиболее доступное решение: регистрация бесплатна, а стоимость пакетов начинается от $9,99. Этот сервис обладает демо-тулом, который хоть и не даст извлечь данные в виде текста, но зато наглядно продемонстрирует качество распознавания.

Я работаю в ABBYY и с радостью отвечу на любые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

У ABBYY  есть рекогнишен, который у меня гадает содержание ШК.
Бесплатный гадатель ШК - это ZXing.

```html
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader() { AutoRotate = true};
reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
reader.Options.PossibleFormats=new List<BarcodeFormat>();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);

using(Drawing.Bitmap bm = new Drawing.Bitmap(fInf.FullName)) {
   Result[] results = reader.DecodeMultiple(bm);
   string strRez = string.Empty;
   if(results != null) {
       foreach(Result result in results)
           strRez = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}: {3}", strRez, strRez == string.Empty ? "" : "\n", result.BarcodeFormat, result.Text);
           Console.WriteLine(strRez);
       }
}
```